# Calculate Z-score on a list of data-frames with NA values in r

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a list of dataframes that contains NA values. I am trying to add a new column to each list that calculates the zscore on a rolling basis from one of the existing columns.

say my list is:

```
df1<- data.frame(a= c(1, 2, NA, NA, 10, NA, 5, NA), b= c(4, NA, 4, NA, NA, 5, 7, NA))
df2<- data.frame(a= c(1, 2, NA, NA, 10, NA, 5, NA), b= c(4, NA, 4, NA, NA, 5, 7, NA))
mylist<- list(df1, df2)
```

my code to run this is

```
for (j in 1:length(mylist)){
  for(i in 1:length(mylist[[j]]))
  mylist[[j]]$z_score[i]<- scale(mylist[[j]]$b[1:i])
}
```

This however produces NA results. Any ideas regarding what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: What is the length of `sup`?

Comment: That was a mistake. The code has now been corrected, thanks

Comment: Scale returns an array and you are loading it to an element of a data frame. Also, change to `scale(mylist[[j]]$b[1:i], scale = 1)`

Comment: Can you show the expected output for the data shared?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
mylist.z <- lapply(mylist, scale)
n <- length(mylist)
for(i in seq(n)) {colnames(mylist.z[[i]]) <- c("az", "bz")}
mylist.2 <- lapply(seq(n), function(i) cbind(mylist[[i]], mylist.z[[i]]))
mylist.2
# [[1]]
#    a  b         az         bz
# 1  1  4 -0.8660254 -0.7071068
# 2  2 NA -0.6185896         NA
# 3 NA  4         NA -0.7071068
# 4 NA NA         NA         NA
# 5 10 NA  1.3608971         NA
# 6 NA  5         NA  0.0000000
# 7  5  7  0.1237179  1.4142136
# 8 NA NA         NA         NA
# 
# [[2]]
#    a  b         az         bz
# 1  1  4 -0.8660254 -0.7071068
# 2  2 NA -0.6185896         NA
# 3 NA  4         NA -0.7071068
# 4 NA NA         NA         NA
# 5 10 NA  1.3608971         NA
# 6 NA  5         NA  0.0000000
# 7  5  7  0.1237179  1.4142136
# 8 NA NA         NA         NA
```